# ¿Como resolver error 422?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy tratando de subir por post un formulario a la base de datos de drupal, pero recibo un error 422 y no logro descubrir el porqué.

Si alguien es capaz de verlo que me de una idea de donde esta mal el código, gracias. Estoy usando también loopback. El error de consola exactamente dice esto: Uncaught (in promise) 422./////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
////api 

export async function notificationPush(info): Promise<Notification> { 
    const response = await fetch(config.apiBaseUrl+'/notification', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(info),
        headers: getHeaders()
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
        return data;
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(response.status);
    }
}

////componente
interface FormValues {
    
    title: string;
    body: string;
    actionType: string;
    actionTarget: string;
    type: number,
    pictureUrl: string,
    sender: string,
    creationDate: string,
    sentDate:string,
    status: number
    
}

const Notification = () => {

    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false)

    ///validacion formulario

  const initialValues: FormValues = {
    title: "",
    body: "",
    actionType: "",
    actionTarget: "",
    type: 0,
    pictureUrl: "",
    sender: "",
    creationDate: "",
    sentDate: "",
    status: 0
     
  };

  const onSubmit = (values: FormValues) => {
    
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(values);
        var data = {
            title: values.title,
            body: values.body,
            actionType: values.actionType,
            actionTarget: values.actionTarget,
            type: values.type,
            pictureUrl: values.pictureUrl,
            sender: values.sender,
            creationDate: values.creationDate,
            sentDate: values.sentDate,
            status: values.status
        };

        notificationPush(data)
        .then((response)=>{
            //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            console.log(response)
            setOpenModal(false);
            // toast.success('Solicitud enviada');
            
        })
        .catch((error)  => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
    }, 500);
  };

  return (
    <>
        <Head>
            <title>Notificaciones - {appTitle}</title>
        </Head>

        <SectionMainFull>
            <SectionTitleLineWithButton icon={mdiBell} title="Notificaciones" main>
                <BaseButton
                onClick={()=>setOpenModal(true)}
                data-modal-toggle="defaultModal"
                
                icon={mdiBellPlusOutline}
                label="Nueva notificación"
                color="icofcv"
                small
                />
            </SectionTitleLineWithButton>
            <CardBox className="mb-6" has-table>
                <TableNotifications />
            </CardBox>
        </SectionMainFull>

        {/* Modal Nueva notificacion*/}

        { openModal === true ?
        <>
        <div id="defaultModal" aria-hidden="true" className="fixed top-0 z-40 inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity "></div>

        <div className="fixed inset-0 z-50 overflow-y-auto ">
            <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 sm:items-center sm:p-0">
                <CardBox className="w-full max-w-5xl">
                    {/* Modal header */}
                    <div className="flex justify-between items-start py-4 rounded-t border-b dark:border-gray-600 mb-4 px-6">
                        <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                            Nueva notificación
                        </h3>
                        <button type="button" className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" data-modal-toggle="defaultModal" onClick={()=> setOpenModal(false)}>
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                            </svg>
                            <span className="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    {/* Modal body */}
                    <div className="p-6 space-y-6">
                        <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                            <Form>
                                <FormField label="Título de notificación">
                                    <Field name="title" placeholder="Titulo" />
                                </FormField>
                            
                                <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                                    <FormField label="Tipo de acción">
                                        <Field name="actionType" as="select" id="">
                                            <option value={''}>Seleccionar</option>
                                            <option value={'0'}>Ninguno</option>
                                            <option value={'1'}>Enlace</option>
                                        </Field>      
                                    </FormField>

                                    <FormField label="Secciones">
                                        <Field name="actionTarget" placeholder="Sección" />
                                    </FormField>     
                                </div>
                            
                                <FormField label="Descripción" hasTextareaHeight>
                                    <Field name="body" as="textarea" placeholder="Tu texto aquí" />
                                </FormField>

                                <FormField label="type" hasTextareaHeight>
                                    <Field name="type"  placeholder="Tu type aquí" />
                                </FormField>

                                <FormField label="pictureUrl" hasTextareaHeight>
                                    <Field name="pictureUrl"  placeholder="Tu pictureUrl aquí" />
                                </FormField>

                                <FormField label="sender" hasTextareaHeight>
                                    <Field name="sender" placeholder="Tu sender aquí" />
                                </FormField>

                                <FormField label="creationDate" hasTextareaHeight>
                                    <Field name="creationDate"  placeholder="Tu creationDate aquí" />
                                </FormField>

                                <FormField label="sentDate" hasTextareaHeight>
                                    <Field name="sentDate"  placeholder="Tu sentDate aquí" />
                                </FormField>

                                <FormField label="status" hasTextareaHeight>
                                    <Field name="status"  placeholder="Tu status aquí" />
                                </FormField>
                                <BaseDivider />
                                <BaseButtons>
                                    <BaseButton type="submit" color="icofcv" label="Aceptar"/>
                                    <BaseButton type="reset" color="icofcv" outline onClick={()=> setOpenModal(false)} label="Cancelar" />
                                </BaseButtons>
                            </Form>
                        </Formik>
                    </div>
                </CardBox>
            </div>
        </div>

        
        </>
        :null
    }

    </>
  )
}

Notification.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return <LayoutAuthenticated>{page}</LayoutAuthenticated>
}

export default Notification
```

Comment: En vez de añadir basura, aprovecha la sugerencia del sitio e incluye en tu pregunta el error completo que sale. Captura de la consola del navegador o algo. Todavía lo puedes hacer yendo a [edit]

Comment: ¿Podrías hacer un `console.log(getHeaders());` antes de la petición `fetch()`. Tiene pinta que estás enviando datos JSON y que el lado de PHP no es capaz de procesarlos (¿quizá porque falte algún encabezado como un `Content-Type`?).

Comment: El console.log(getHeaders()) me da este resultado en consola:

Comment: {content-type: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', Authorization: 'Bearer eyJraWQiOiJ0a25OakZoTlcxXC8xNjlCSVwvQklHYm5…ZoDAfZ8j1fonDMxjuWMnmpCWhyJ-EOvRw1783KuksD_Z7h06Q'}

Comment: Te planteo que utilices una herramienta externa (por ej, Postman) para hacer la llamada desde esa app al PHP, y ver si te está devolviendo bien los datos. Luego de eso ya revisas la parte front

Comment: Ya lo e resuelto, había datos mal puestos que no lograba procesar,.gracias por los consejos.